# Using Drupal's Core classes as services

Tags: 9, services

I have rather a general question that would help me to undestand using services in Drupal 8+ and when it is worth to do so.

I have found a useful method createFromRoute which is part of

> namespace Drupal\Core;

It is defined in Link.php file.

I have found plethora of examples in code when it is just called like this

```
Link::createFromRoute(... parameters here)
```

But, is calling this method like that a good practice? Should't this be somehow used as a service?

Why yes/no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`\Drupal\Core\Link`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Link.php/class/Link/9) class is not used to implement a service and its [`createFromRoute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AcreateFromRoute/9) method is static. The only way to call it is like [`CommentBreadcrumbBuilder::build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21src%21CommentBreadcrumbBuilder.php/function/CommentBreadcrumbBuilder%3A%3Abuild/9) does, for example.

```php
$breadcrumb->addLink(Link::createFromRoute($this->t('Home'), '<front>'));
```

You could also directly create an instance of the `Link` class, as that same method does.

```php
$breadcrumb->addLink(new Link($entity->label(), $entity->toUrl()));
```

`Link::__construct()` requires the text to show in the link and the URL, differently from `Link::createFromRoute()` which requires the text to show in the link and the route name.
(This means that, when you are creating the link from a route, `Link::createFromRoute()` is the method you want to use.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now this is finally clear to me!